# Authenticating to wireless with EAP-TLS in separate forests with the same trusted root CA

Tags: pki

I'm looking at a scenario of having a standalone offline root CA sign a subordinate CA in two separate active directory forests on different campuses.

If I then set up EAP-TLS on each site, will I be able to authenticate with EAP-TLS on either campus if the client has a computer certificate from either subordinate CA?

Assume the client trusts the root CA.

Comment: After a short reading it seems like EAP-TLS is essentially standard TLS (though quite often with client-certs). This means that if you configure your endpoints who do the server-side negotiation to request / accept anything issued under the common root (as opposed to only accepting client certs issued under their local intermediate CA), then the other forest's certificates will be accepted.